# Powershell | Unable to perform command with space character

Tags: powershell

Can anyone explain to me why:

```
iex "C:\Program Files\test\test.exe"
```

Returns:

> C:\Program : The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + C:\Program Files\test\test.exe
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

---

I've tried to get this working multiple different ways:

- Wrapping the text in `()`
- Putting the string into a variable and passing it as a variable instead
- Using single quotes
- Using double quotes

I don't know how else I can get it to realize that the entire string must be run, not just the first word.

---

**Post-answered example**

The question has been answered. Here is something I was trying to get working:

```
$tool = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
$param = "/c ping google.com -n 1"
$test = & $tool $param
Write-Host $test
```

It turns out that the line with `&` does NOT work with double quotes `""` in this instance, and actually worked without them. I think this has to do with there being arguments/parameters involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `&` operator together with quotes:

```
& "C:\Program Files\test\test.exe"
```

---

From `help about_operators`:

> ```
>   & Call operator
>      Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as
>      the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in
>      variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not
>      parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters. 
>
>          C:\PS> $c = "get-executionpolicy"
>          C:\PS> $c
>          get-executionpolicy
>
>          C:\PS> & $c
>          AllSigned
> ```

Comment: So is this thing only failing because it's a call to an executable in a directory, and MUST be preceded by an `&` symbol?

Comment: You need to use quotes because of the space, but when you do that, PowerShell thinks you've just entered a string. For example, if you typed `"hello"` in quotes, PowerShell wouldn't try to execute it. It's just a string. That's why you need the & "call operator" when the string represents a command.

Comment: Alright, looks like I got what I needed to work without the quotes. I'll put it in my question so you know what I'm talking about.